# I am having a problem with the insert of the AVL class

Tags: java

What is happening is that my variable parent keeps being set to null when it should be set to this everytime I declare a new AVLTree. I put the print statements on the insert method to check whether parent was being changed or kept null.

```
public class AVLTree < T extends Comparable< T >> extends BinaryTree< T >{

   private int balance ;

   private AVLTree<T> parent;

   public AVLTree(T item){

      this(item,null);
   }

   public AVLTree(T item, AVLTree<T> parent){

      super(item);

      this.balance = 0;

      this.parent = parent;
   }

   public AVLTree<T> insert(T item){

      if(this.item.compareTo(item) < 0){
     if(this.left != null){     
            this.left.insert(item);
     }
      else{
        this.left= new AVLTree<T>(item, this);
        System.out.println("parent key " + this.parent.item);
      }
      }
      else{
     if(this.right != null){
            this.right.insert(item);
     }
     else{ 
        this.right = new AVLTree<T>(item, this);
        System.out.print("parent key " + this.parent.item);     
     }
      } 
      return rotations();      

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't particularly clear, but if I understood it correctly: calling `new AVLTree<T>(item, this)` doesn't and shouldn't change `this.parent`.

It creates a new `AVLTree` and *its* `parent` will be `this`, because the `this` in the constructor refers to the instance being constructed, not to the caller.

I.e. after

```
this.left= new AVLTree<T>(item, this);
```

you'll see `this.left.parent == this`, *not* `this.parent == this`.

Comment: I see. Well then the question I have is how do I change parent from being null to have the value of this(the tree that was inserted two times before the one being inserted)

Comment: You can just set `this.parent = whatever_you_need;`.